# Transforming XML with XSL and self closing tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<run>
    <font style="bold"/>Some Wording
</run>
```

I want to transform it to

```
<p>
    <b>Some Wording</b>
</p>
```

I am trying this template

```
<xsl:template match="run/font[@style='bold']">
    <p>
        <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </b>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

but this gives the output

```
<p>
    <b/>Some Wording
</p>
```

How do I wrap the wording in the `<b>` tags using XSLT?

Comment: The output is correct. The `<font>` tag has no content, and so therefore does your `<b>` tag. The text `Some wording` is not a child of the `<font>` tag, so there is no reason to boldface it.

Comment: Yes, I realise it is correct as written, but it is not what I want to produce.  The wording is a child of the `<run>` tag, but I only want to apply the `<b>` tags when the wording is preceded by a `<font style="bold">` tag.

Comment: Can’t see you can do it. Your input file is weird. You should be wrapping your text with a bold element.

Comment: Can you do a if check to see if a relative is as you desire and if so wrap in the chosen tag?

Comment: Or try selecting the value of a relative rather than the active value. I am not a xsl guru. But maybe selecting the value of a sibling or child. Not sure.

Comment: I don't see how you would get that result, it should rather give `<p><b></b></p>Some Wording`. As for wrapping the sibling text of the empty `font` element, which XSLT processor, which version of XSLT  do you use/can you use? And how generic does the solution need to be? For that simple sample with that simple result it is easy, but if you expect to process all kind of variations of several `font` elements with different styles it is a more complex programming task.

Comment: So if it's correct why do you want to change it? The problem here is in the input, not the transform. And if you need to change it, what is the underlying principle? Every sibling of such a `<font>` element? Every post-sibling? Every sibling/post-sibling and their children? Text elements only? You need to characterize your problem properly ... and once having done that, expressing it in XSLT is trivial.

Comment: The output was correct for the XSL I was using, but it wasn't giving the desired result.  I was looking for the result I showed.  I agree that the input is the issue, but it is not an input I have any control over - I need to code around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to wrap any text node that is immediately preceded by `<font style="bold"/>` in a `<b>` element, you can achieve that with

```
<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::font][@style='bold']]">
  <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
</xsl:template>
```

If that's not your requirement (inferring requirements from one example is notoriously error-prone) then you need to explain it more clearly.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  That did the trick.  I just needed to terminate the `<b>` and it worked.

Comment: I've fixed the typo.